# Multiple Domains on a single G Suite account?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I have 5 domains. (Different blogs, etc.) Can I add all of these domains to a single G Suite account? Or do I need to create a new account for each website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain aliases or secondary domains can be added on existing G suite account given that they are not used anywhere else on Google. This Google support link contains more information including limitations of using multiple accounts. https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295